# Ubuntu keeps dismounting external USB disk on rsync

Tags: ubuntu, usb, rsync, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on a Windows 10 host in VirtualBox. I'm trying to `rsync` a large folder (192GB) onto an external USB hard drive enclosure (Orico USB 3.0 2.5 SATA III) containing a Samsung 830 SSD (240GB). The disk is formatted as NTFS, and I have `ntfs-3g` installed on Ubuntu.

The operation starts out fine, but at some point the `rsync` fails and the USB seems to have unmounted:

`rsync` output:

```
rsync: rename "/mnt/usb/bitcoin/blocks/.blk00201.dat.vptzQx" -> "blocks/blk00201.dat": Input/output error (5)
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/usb/bitcoin/blocks/.blk00202.dat.QAivPb" failed: Input/output error (5)
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/usb/bitcoin/blocks/.blk00203.dat.XoflbV" failed: Input/output error (5)
...
```

I can see in VirtualBox that the USB drive has been unmounted:

[image: usb unmounted]

I'm not sure which logs I can check to see why it's unmounting. Suggestions?

Comment: If the USB device is "passed through", it might be because of USB UAS bugs and incompatibilities. The easiest would be in virtualbox to force USB to be 2.0 instead of 3.0 (I don't know how). This will disable UAS (as well as slowing down transfers of course). If rsync then works, you'll have to search on how to disable uas with USB3. Eg, these answers of mine: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418326/how-do-i-make-my-seagate-2tb-usb-hdd-work-in-linux/418348#418348 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437036/odroid-xu4-hdd-dies-after-10-minutes-on-usb-3-0/437087#437087

Comment: Yeah, I can try and get virtualbox to use USB 2.0, thanks!

Comment: That didn't work either :( seems to have dismounted after a while, here's the dmesg logs: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/donnielrt/ae12d385a4bd177cd5b049fb9b695b0a/raw/e7f4ac0010e12a54bc84b1c2a7e9b617bef7298f/dmesg-logs

Comment: I notice in dmesg that the drive seems to be using UAS, I'm going to try disabling it per your links.

Comment: Failed again :( it seems to have blacklisted the USB drive, but it's still failing:

[    1.780078] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected

[    1.780680] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 2537 pid 1068: 800000

[    1.780723] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0

[    1.780837] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage

[    1.784023] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas

Comment: you have to retrieve the usb VID:PID values (`lsusb`) to construct =VID:PID:u , and you'd better pass the option both as kernel parameter (at boot) and module option if you're not sure. Anyway as long as UAS is loaded, you will just not even know if all your troubles are because of UAS or not (but I would think it is)

Comment: @A.B I have in `local-disable-usb.conf`: `options usb-storage quirks=2537:1068:u` (2537:1068), and in `disable-uas.conf`: `install uas /bin/false`. It looks like UAS isn't being used anymore (the "registered new interface driver uas") no longer displays in dmesg. Can you explain the "at boot" and "module" options, please?