# USB-device 'unmounts' itself while syncronising data with rsync on Centos Stream 8

Tags: centos, mount, usb-device

**Problem:** the mounted USB-device 'unmounts' itself and 'vanishes' spontaneously while synchronizing data with `rsync`.

- **Device:** USB-stick PNY 512GB USB 3.1 formatted as `ext4` (see below
  information from *gparted*) mounted as `/dev/sdc1`
- **Laptop:** Lenovo ThinkPad T480s
- **System:** *Centos 8 Stream*

Some screenshots from system diagnostics:

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3] [image: 4]

Further information on `/dev/sdc1`

```
(base) [doris@serenity ~]$ udevadm info /dev/sdc1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
N: sdc1
S: disk/by-id/usb-PNY_USB_3.2.1_FD_90001761B9520F09-0:0-part1
S: disk/by-label/serenity
S: disk/by-partuuid/507148a2-01
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
S: disk/by-uuid/d314e11b-178f-4236-a1c4-ff373533c839
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-PNY_USB_3.2.1_FD_90001761B9520F09-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-partuuid/507148a2-01 /dev/disk/by-label/serenity /dev/disk/by-uuid/d314e11b-178f-4236-a1c4-ff373533c839 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdc1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FS_LABEL=serenity
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=serenity
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=d314e11b-178f-4236-a1c4-ff373533c839
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=d314e11b-178f-4236-a1c4-ff373533c839
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=USB_3.2.1_FD
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x203.2.1\x20FD\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=00ed
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:32
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2048
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=968712192
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0x83
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=507148a2-01
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=507148a2
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=PMAP
E: ID_SCSI=1
E: ID_SCSI_INQUIRY=1
E: ID_SERIAL=PNY_USB_3.2.1_FD_90001761B9520F09-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=90001761B9520F09
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=PNY
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=PNY\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=154b
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=33
E: PARTN=1
E: SCSI_MODEL=USB_3.2.1_FD
E: SCSI_MODEL_ENC=USB\x203.2.1\x20FD\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: SCSI_REVISION=PMAP
E: SCSI_TPGS=0
E: SCSI_TYPE=disk
E: SCSI_VENDOR=PNY
E: SCSI_VENDOR_ENC=PNY\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4257020873
```

**Observations:**

- *gparted* needs a long time to scan sdc1
- issues started the first time after setting-up the laptop newly and switching to *Centos Stream*
- the usb-device was purchased a couple of days ago
- the owner is `root`, all permission set to `root`
- the usb drivers are `usb-storage` not `uas` (reported to be problematic by
  various users --> see [Linux keeps connecting and disconnecting USB
  mounted external drives](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=320801) or [Ubuntu keeps dismounting external USB
  disk on rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448971/ubuntu-keeps-dismounting-external-usb-disk-on-rsync)
- the device is labelled as *serenity* which is also the laptop's name (in case this matters ...)
- I just tried to simply `copy/paste` the entire `home` directory within the *nautilus* to the device and until now it did NOT yet unmount spontaneously (however, that is not a long term solution because it takes forever!)

**UPDATE:** `copy/pasting` files worked perfectly without interruption.

Comment: Please show us also the command line with `rsync`. Have you checked/repaired the ext4 file system on the USB drive, that is is healthy? Could it be the the buffers were full and the write management was overloaded? It could happen if a Linux driver *or* an internal driver in the USB drive is buggy. Have you tried when connected to some other USB port on the computer or when all other USB devices are disconnected?  Maybe try with some other Linux distro and/or kernel version? Or try in another computer?

Comment: Hello @sudodus, thanks for your comments!

The `rsync` command is: `>>rsync -avz /home/doris/ /run/media/doris/serenity`

I have not checked if the `ext4` file system is healthy, but the USB device was newly formatted.

I do not know about the buffers, please explain.

I have not connected to some other computer, because I do not have one.

I will try some updates and see if that helps. Copying the files was no problem, so I guess it is not a hardware problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you copy within the same computer, not via a network. In this case I would not use -z, alias --compress. I think the slow part (bottleneck) in your case is the memory cells (the hardware in the USB drive), and the compression would have to be extracted before writing anyway, which might be 'too much' for the USB system. - Buffers: modern operating systems perform tasks rapidly and store the result, when writing to files, intermediately in RAM and the CPU will be ready for new tasks. Then, at a slower rate the data are written to the memory cells of the target device.

Comment: Maybe it would help with the option --outbuf=MODE (and change from full buffering to None or Line). But it might have no effect on the kind of buffering that might get overloaded. Maybe it would help with the option --bwlimit=RATE (and limit the transfer rate), so that the target drive has a chance to receive what is written to the buffers. - I remember a case some years ago, when the  a certain rsync command failed writing to a USB pendrive in 32-bit Linux, but succeeded in 64-bit Linux. I solved that by using tar instead of rsync. I think the problem was to manage 'many small files'.

Comment: @sudodus, thanks for your insights. That sounds reasonable. I was just wondering that I do not have the same problem when I `rsync` to the external hard drive (also via USB) but maybe a USB-stick (device) is a different thing as an external drive. I let you know if your strategy works when `rsync` the next time.

Comment: I'm looking forward to your result. Good luck :-)