# blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdx. Disk fails after boot

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, nas

I'm trying to create a personal home media server using Raspberry Pi 4 model B with OMV. I'm connecting four external hard drives through a single USB hub with a dedicated power source.

At first, when I set up the media server, everything worked out well, but after an hour or so, all the disks were unmounted and failed to remount. The problem is that no drives are shown in the `/dev` folder, so I can't perform any disk checks.
After it was unmounted for the first time, it will start to get unmounted immediately after I reboot. This was an issue with other hardware using OMV or a custom SMB config from scratch.
When using OMV, I can edit the `/etc/openmediavault/config.xml` to remove the shared folders and mounted drive information and reboot to make the disk readable again, but it will fail after a couple of hours and never get mounted again unless I remove the config entry.

Here is the log for `dmesg`: https://pastebin.com/4Synf8ZC

So my question is:

1. Why do all the disks get unmounted? I suspect the issue is with the USB hub being unstable or broken somehow.
2. If it's a hardware issue, why does the disk never mounts again after it fails for the first time but always mounts successfully for the first couple of hours?

Comment: Q/A with answers of mine to work around this problem (which is about UAS): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418326/how-do-i-make-my-seagate-2tb-usb-hdd-work-in-linux , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437036/odroid-xu4-hdd-dies-after-10-minutes-on-usb-3-0