# Is my brand new USB SSD defective?

Tags: mount, usb, hard-disk, usb-drive, ssd

I've had a few times this problem in the past few days (but not in the previous weeks and I haven't changed anything besiders package updates) in a Debian 12 system (kernel 6.1 - haven't tried 6.6) with a USB-C 1TB SSD. At some random moment, without any special activity (like just browsing the web) the disk becomes non-accessible with `input/output error` on files. I see USB disconnects in the logs but there are so many different errors that I don't know what to search. I try to remount it as a workaround but it says that the device is read-only.

Both the SSD and the laptop are brand new. It has a LUKS ext4 partition (I guess that encryption makes things worse) that uses the whole disk.

Do this error lines mean that part of the sectors of the disk are defective?

```
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: usb 2-1: cmd cmplt err -108
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 17 de fe e8 00 00 28 00
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 17 de fe e8 00 00 28 00
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 400490216 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 5 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 17826766 starting block 50024157)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 50024157
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 17826766 starting block 50024158)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653328 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044546)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044546
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044547
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044548
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653392 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044554)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044554
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653408 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044556)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044556
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653472 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044564)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044564
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044565
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044566
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 24044567
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653512 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044569)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653528 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044571)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192653728 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24044596)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192657040 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 17 writing to inode 17463405 starting block 24045010)
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 192657064 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 0, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 10, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 12, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 26, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 27, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 28, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 35, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 47, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 56, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 61, lost async page write
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:6: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:4: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:4: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:3: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:3: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:0: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:0: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:0: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:217: comm kworker/u24:0: Error while async write back metadata                                                                                                                                                 
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus systemd[1]: Stopped target cryptsetup.target - Local Encrypted Volumes.
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus systemd[1]: Stopped target local-fs.target - Local File Systems.
Dec 22 17:54:49 d12asus systemd[1]: Unmounting boot-efi.mount - /boot/efi...
```

Things I've tried without luck:

- plug the USB-C the other way around
- read-only `badblocks` from a live Linux system showed no errors
- I prefer not to do a read-write `badblocks` but I tried to fill up the whole disk to see if there is some issue for writing on defective sectors or files but there were no errors either
- `smartctl` can't read the SMART info on Linux or Windows, but CrystalDiskInfo says that everything is OK with the disk
- it had the `remount-ro` option in fstab, I removed it but it gets remounted read only anyway
- update all packages with `apt`
- use UUIDs instead of device names
- I can't mount it on Windows, but there are no USB disconnects of the device itself even after many hours, on the same laptop

Did I get a disk with bad sectors?

Even if it has this problem, can I remount it back read-write when this happens?

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem is gone after changing the distro's v6.1 kernel to linux-xanmod-x64v4 v6.6

Comment: `smartctl` should be able to read SMART info under Linux or you can install the Windows version of the utility and run it under Windows but even without that your errors are strongly indicative of a HW failure.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  Both Linux and Windows versions of `smartctl` seem to not support this disk. I tried with different `-d` options

Comment: There are several cases of incompatibility with UAS mode (usually because the vendor screwed with the firmware). Your logs show you're using UAS. Try disabling it and see if it works reliably then. Some Q/As (where I made an answer): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437036/odroid-xu4-hdd-dies-after-10-minutes-on-usb-3-0 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418326/how-do-i-make-my-seagate-2tb-usb-hdd-work-in-linux

Comment: @A.B I'm going to try that. First quirk `t` and then `u`. Do you know if quirk `t` also disables TRIM? I definitely want to keep TRIM for the disk lifespan

Comment: Can't tell. Without TRIM, if the FTL is good enough ("repaints" the whole disk when writing a sector enough times) I believe using only half the capacity, ie formatting to use only half while the disk was not yet written to much, should help for lifespan by limiting [write amplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification#Free_user_space). That's the only way for USB keys, since they don't have UAS (but they still have their internal spare).

Comment: Is your USB SSD from a reputable source? This is a typical behavior of "fake drives" - A much smaller capacity drive (likely just a microSD, not actually a SSD) - with a modified firmware to report a lot more than it is - but can be a factory defect. https://askubuntu.com/a/753161/1210606

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, it's from Crucial (although reported as Micron Technology). The shop is Amazon

Comment: Amazon has LOTS of fakes and what it says in enclosure (brand) isn't really relevant (scammers scam with reputable brands most of the times). If you can find it here https://www.crucial.com/products/ssd/portable-ssds?cm_mmc=bing-_-us-_-brand-_-external&ef_id=:G:s&gclsrc=3p.ds and the price was similar then you probably should contact Amazon ASAP to report the defect, If significantly cheaper then you got your answer, contact Amazon to report the counterfeit product.

Comment: @ChanganAuto this doesn't look like a fake drive at all. Fake drives have consecutive errors while accessing sectors, for the OP they look random.

Comment: There's probably no point looking beyond the first line, "USB disconnect", as all the following errors are just consequential.  As to the cause of the disconnect, your drive might not be getting enough peak power from the usb port (eg at random housekeeping times), or as A.B suggests there may be a protocol incompatibility/bug. Try using another port, disconnecting other usb devices, using a powered external hub, running with the laptop on charge, using a very short high quality usb cable. Lookup the maxpower requirements for the ssd. Look for firmware updates for the ssd.

Comment: @meuh It has to be a protocol/driver thing, as it works fine on Windows, but that's a nice checklist to have at hand

Comment: Please post your last edit as an answer, and then you can accept it (possibly after a delay) and the question will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

These two solutions seem to work fine, although it's impossible to reproduce the problem reliably:

- Using the USB storage quirks as in [How do I make my Seagate 2Tb usb hdd work in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418326/how-do-i-make-my-seagate-2tb-usb-hdd-work-in-linux) or [Odroid XU4: HDD dies after 10 minutes on USB 3.0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437036/odroid-xu4-hdd-dies-after-10-minutes-on-usb-3-0)
- Changing the distro's v6.1 kernel to linux-xanmod-x64v4 v6.6 (the distro's v6.6 kernel should work fine too)